# Trimming data from list to fit in a specific shape such as a geodataframe map

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, geopandas, colormap

I have a bunch of approximated data in a list from which I create a color map. I have overlaid this map onto a map which was drawn from a geodataframe containing a shape file (with all coordinates of the polygon boundaries. In the picture below you can see that the cmap does not conform to the shape of the map.

To make things look cleaner, I would like to somehow 'trim' the edges off of the color map. How could I go about doing this? I have tried using df.totalbounds to conditionally do calculations before the colormap data is made, but this produces the results seen in the photo linked below.

Any solutions or input are appreciated, thanks!

Code snippet of the conditional calculation described above where geo_minx/y and geo_maxx/y are the min and max (x,y) values taken from the df.totalbounds method.

```
if geo_minx <= realx <= geo_maxx and geo_miny <= realy <= geo_maxy:
```

[Map with color map over a geodataframe shape file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHRFw.jpg)

**Edit**
Here is the structure of the dataframe that holds each approximated data point with its (x,y) coordinates:

```
approximated data
       X     Y    approx
0 -124.6  24.6  1.006655
1 -124.6  24.8  1.006655
2 -124.6  25.0  1.006655
3 -124.6  25.2  1.006655
4 -124.6  25.4  1.006655
```

Here is the map dataframe struture

```
<bound method NDFrame.head of    STATEFP   STATENS     AFFGEOID GEOID  ... LSAD         ALAND        AWATER                                           geometry
0       28  01779790  0400000US28    28  ...   00  121533519481    3926919758  MULTIPOLYGON (((-88.50297 30.21523, -88.49176 ...
1       37  01027616  0400000US37    37  ...   00  125923656064   13466071395  MULTIPOLYGON (((-75.72681 35.93584, -75.71827 ...
2       40  01102857  0400000US40    40  ...   00  177662925723    3374587997  POLYGON ((-103.00257 36.52659, -103.00219 36.6...
3       51  01779803  0400000US51    51  ...   00  102257717110    8528531774  MULTIPOLYGON (((-75.74241 37.80835, -75.74151 ...
4       54  01779805  0400000US54    54  ...   00   62266474513     489028543  POLYGON ((-82.64320 38.16909, -82.64300 38.169.
```

Comment: You can make shapely Points of your data and use `geopandas.clip` to keep only those within the shape.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you elaborate on how to do this?

Comment: You have to show some of your data and including the structure of your dataframes.

Comment: @martinfleis The data frame structures are posted above in an edit. Thank you again.